# Node.js code in html file

Tags: html, node.js

It is possible to mix HTML with node.js commands?
I want to make my site like in PHP so:

```
<html>
<!-- Some HTML -->
<?php 
    echo "example";
?>
</html>
```

So, server makes all commands, which are included in HTML file and than returns pure HTML to show it in users browser. I need this, because I want to get data from MySQL database and then show it on my site.

In all tutorials I found only:

```
res.write("<Some html>");
```

And there is nothing about keeping html in separate files and add to them some server-side js.

Comment: One difference between PHP and Node is that PHP has a default templating engine built in (the one you're using), while node does not. Both have many choices of good downloadable templating engines though.

Answer (score 2):

Find a templating engine and build your application around that, because what you want is not possible.
For a list of compatible template engines, take a look here:
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

Answer (score 1):

Your example using Express and EJS (which I use).  Jade seems like overkill to me, but that's just my opinion.

```
// index.ejs (the html template)
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div><%= example %></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your node app:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {
        layout: false,
        locals: {
            example: "Hello world!"
        }
    });
});
```

That's pretty much the basics of using EJS.  I personally like it over Jade because the people I use to do up the html don't hand it to me in Jade format, and it's very similar to how I used to do php templating.

There is more you can do with the templates of course, you can put javascript in them to say, loop through an array returned by a database, include other .ejs files.  You just need to dig into the docs and examples on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `res.write` is enough.

You can generate some string with html syntax, like `"<html>..</html>"`, then you put it into the `res.write` and you get response with a html file.
The point is how to generate the string with html syntax.

If we have a template file like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ "Hello" + " world!" }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

We want to get the `"Hello world!"` between `<h1>` and `</h1>`. So we can have the work done by:

1. read the template file with `fs.readFile`
2. use regular expression to get the content between `{{` and `}}`
3. use `eval` to evaluate the content, and replace them.

After doing this, you can get the string with html syntax. and that is what most template engines(like [ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs), [jade](http://jade-lang.com/)) do, of course they have more complex works to do.

I hope that this can help you know more about template engine with node.js, and please forgive my poor English...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `web application framework` like express?

[Check it out here!](http://expressjs.com/)